# How to Find P(E) and P(F)

Tags: probability

If $$P(E \cap F) = 0.054$$ $$P(E |F) = 0.12$$ $$P(F | E) = 0.3$$

How Do I find P(F) or P(E)?

These are dependent of each other, so I was trying to use the fact that

$$P(E \cap F) =  P(E |F)P(F)$$

By using this, I could isolate P(F) but that is not working. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: What's not working about it?

Comment: I get P(F) = $P(E |F)/P(E \cap F)$ but the answers don't match

Comment: @user274065 $P(F)=P(E\cap F)/P(E\mid F)$.

Comment: Not working??? Substitution gives you: $0.054=0.12\times P(F)$. Now can you find $P(F)$?

Comment: @user274065 What answer were you expecting? It might be that the textbook has an error in its answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$P(E\mid F)=\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)}$$
and
$$P(F\mid E)=\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(E)}.$$
Hence,
$$P(F)=\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(E\mid F)}$$
and
$$P(E)=\frac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F\mid E)}.$$